# Interpretation of results on the studies of "Moral Hypocrisy"

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, moral-psychology, prosocial-behavior

Hello right now I am dealing with the studies of C.Daniel Batson, who provided several studies and experiments to reveal moral hypocrisy. I think that I understand the basic idea of his theory, however I am not really able to interpret his statistic outcomes.

I do not know if some of you have access to the full text, but the study is listed under the title:

**In a very different voice: Unmasking moral hypocrisy**.
Batson, C. Daniel; Kobrynowicz, Diane; Dinnerstein, Jessica L.; Kampf, Hannah C.; Wilson, Angela D.
Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, **Vol 72(6)**, **Jun 1997**, 1335-1348

However, I will provide some relevant excerpts in the form of pictures for better comprehension towards my question.

First excerpts:

[image]

In this part Batson et. al. presents his results and compare them through the previously measured responsibility measures indexes. The confusing part starts from the yellow lined part. I do not really understand what does he mean by coding?

Furthermore, he mentions that only one of this applied measures correlated with the results and provides the result **r(18)=0,39, p< 0,05** (blue lined). This is the core of my real problem. First of all I do not really understand what does the r(18) mean? I think it has something to do with a normal distribution right? Moreover, I have no idea how to read the 0,39 in a clear way. Does it mean that 39% of the results actually are coherent with the previously applied measurement indexes of moral responsibility? In the end I also struggle to interpret the p-vale of 0,05. Does it mean that the value (0,39) would be theoretically rejected, if it would be below 0,05?

To demonstrate the full results I also provide you the second excerpt:

[image]

I really struggling to understand this notations. The worst thing is that it is not explained in the whole text, how these numbers have to be interpret. I also read several other psychological texts, which have very similar expressions.

I hope that my question is somehow understandable, because it is very difficult to ask this question, if nobody has an access to the full text. I would be extremely grateful, if someone could help me.

Best Regards.